# R: Generate tables based on Distinct Values

Tags: r

Good Morning, Community:

I have this table, which contains demand for specific items, on a given location and a given date:

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/RAoXIbW"><a href="//imgur.com/RAoXIbW"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Assuming the demand is already grouped (Sum) by Date, Product ID and Location ID, is there a way of generating several tables based distinct Product IDs and Location IDs, containing their respective demand in R?

This how it would look like for product "a" on location "3":

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/wv1hBxP"><a href="//imgur.com/wv1hBxP"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `split` to split the datasets into several in a `list` and then we can extract different datasets from the `list`

```
lst1 <- split(df1, list(df1$ProductID, df1$LocationID), drop = TRUE)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening,
if your data is stored in a dataframe, say df, then

```
df[df["Product ID"]=="a",]
```

returns the data filtered for product "a".

Comment: Don't think so. Where?